# How to authenticate to Bluemix CF API using Python

Tags: python, api, oauth, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

Let me preface by saying I'm probably overlooking something simple.

I'm attempting to script some manipulation of my Bluemix account with Python and the CF API.

First get to https://api.ng.bluemix.net/info to get the authorization_endpoint, https://login.ng.bluemix.net/UAALoginServerWAR/

```
response = requests.get('https://api.ng.bluemix.net/info')
```

Then post to authorization_endpoint to get oauth token.

```
results = response.json()
auth_endpoint = results['authorization_endpoint'] + 'oauth/token?grant_type=password&client=cf'
http_payload = {
    'username': id,
    'password': pw,
    'client_id': 'cf'
    }
auth = ('cf', '')
response = requests.post(auth_endpoint, data=http_payload, auth=auth)
```

Then use the returned oauth token to call the CF API, in this case https://api.ng.bluemix.net/v2/organizations.

```
results = response.json()
url = 'https://api.ng.bluemix.net/v2/organizations'
authorization = results['token_type'] + ' ' + results['access_token']
http_headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'authorization': authorization
    }
response = requests.get(url, headers=http_headers)
```

But this results in a 404, {"description": "Unknown request", "error_code": "CF-NotFound",  "code": 10000}. Is this the right approach? What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
id = 'changeme'
pw = 'changeme'

import json
import urllib
import requests

response = requests.get('https://api.ng.bluemix.net/info')
results = response.json()
auth_endpoint = results['authorization_endpoint'] + '/oauth/token'

data = 'grant_type=password&username={0}&password={1}'.format(id, pw)
auth = ('cf', '')
headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
    }
response = requests.post(auth_endpoint, data=data, headers=headers, auth=auth)

results = response.json()
url = 'https://api.ng.bluemix.net/v2/organizations'
authorization = results['token_type'] + ' ' + results['access_token']
http_headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'authorization': authorization
    }
response = requests.get(url, headers=http_headers)

print(response.text)
```

Returns:

```
{
  "total_results": 6,
  "total_pages": 1,
  "prev_url": null,
  "next_url": null,
  "resources": [
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes. This works for me too. I was looking in the wrong place for my error. I thought it was with how I was generating the token. But after getting my access to work with curl commands I realized that my error was a simpler and a stupid typo. The URL I used was https:\\api.ng.bluemix.net\V2\. At some point I managed to capitalize the 'v'.